# Perform a search using the installed search engines using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, search-engine, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to perform a search using search engines in the Firefox search engine box .

I can access the engines with the following code

```
// quick Proof of Concept code
const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");

var browserSearchService = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/search-service;1"]
                         .getService(Ci.nsIBrowserSearchService);

var test = browserSearchService.getEngines();
//I can query test.attribute for each engine
```

I have found no way to execute a search using the installed search engines using JavaScript. Does anyone know how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this example i look for an open window as it opens the search results in a new tab. but you don't need to do that. you can use XHR. if yo uwanted to do that just take the `submission` parameters seen below and instead of plugging them into `win.openLinkIn` then plug it into XHR.

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm'); 
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
if (!win) {
    throw new Error('no win found of type "navigator:browser" is open');
}

var engineName = 'NAME OF INSTALLED ENGINE YOU WANT TO SEARCH WITH HERE';
console.log('enigneName:', engineName)

var engine = Services.search.getEngineByName(engineName)
if (!engine) {
    throw new Error('could not find engine with name of "' + engineName + '"');
}
var searchText = 'i want to search this value'; //if you want currently filled in text of search bar do this: win.BrowserSearch.searchBar.value
var submission = engine.getSubmission(searchText, null, 'searchbar');

var useNewTab = true;
var inBg = false; //if use new tab do you want to open it in background or foreground?

win.openLinkIn(submission.uri.spec,
    useNewTab ? 'tab' : 'current', {
        postData: submission.postData,
        inBackground: inBg,
        relatedToCurrent: true //set this to true, if you are opening in new tab AND want the tab to sit next to it, if you are opening in new tab and set this to false then the new tab will open at end of tab bar
    });
```

if you want to get a list of the available search engine names you can do this:

```
var engines = Services.search.getVisibleEngines();
var engineNames = [];
for (var i=0; i<engines.length; i++) {
  engineNames.push(engines[i].name);
}
console.log('engine names of the installed engines:', engineNames);
```

Comment: Thank you Noitidart! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Noitidart but do you know if / how I can get a search engine's icon ?. I wish to use it in a data.url format. I looked in the array of engines and it lists the icons as null or shows getIcons methonds with native code and my searches thus far have been fruitless. Any ideas ?

Comment: No problem at all no sorrys man. Get it like this `Services.search.getEngineByName('Bing').iconURI.spec`

Comment: Thank again Noitidart. It seems Bing is the only one that actually has an icon. That explains why I could not get them.

Comment: @hooray what are you other engines I have 7 search engines and all of them have icons: http://i.imgur.com/gMfPd6d.png if it has icon in the search bar you should be able to access it.

Comment: I was using the default engines when testing. Bing was the only one that returned an image the rest returned null. I'm using iceweasel but I doubt that would make any difference in this case.

Comment: @hooray do the other engines in your search bar have an icon when you make the drop down show like i did in my screenshot? If its just a dashed square then you're right they don't have an icon. But if an icon shows in the searchbar it definitely has an icon.

Comment: Yes they all show as having icons but when I try `Services.search.getEngineByName('Google').iconURI.spec` for example it comes back null. If I log the engine objects the IconURI property for the others is null.

Comment: @hooray that is absolutely weird. I just copied pasted that code and i got a data uri for it. There are some functions in `Services.search.getEngineByName('Google')` that you can invesitigate: `getIcons` and `getIconURLBySize`. But thats absolutely weird you're getting `null`, you shouldn't. If it has an image in the search bar it definitely has an icon uri. Try `console.log(Services.search.getEngineByName('Google').iconURI)` and see what it shows in VariableViewer in browser console on click.

Comment: I tried getIcons and getIconURLBySize initially before asking you about the icons. It looks like it is something on my end. I'll try it on a proper firefox when I get a chance and see if it is an iceweasel issue.

Comment: Cool man let me know how it goes, as an ultra final last resort *if it really doesnt work*, you can find an open window with a search bar, then get the xul element with the corresponding engine name and get the data uri that way, but this is not reliable as such a window may not be open (on startup windows load) and it only shows visible engines info there.

Comment: Thanks. I have it working now. For some reason only some of the images show Google, Yahoo,Amazon,Ebay and Wikipedia Don't show.  I added a check which stopped the null errors.                                                                     exports.getIcons = function(){
    
        var engines = Services.search.getVisibleEngines();
        var icons = new Array();

        for (var i=0;i<engines.length;i++){
            if(engines[i].iconURI)    
                icons[i] =Services.search.getEngineByName(engines[i].name).iconURI.spec;

        }   
        return icons;
    };

Comment: Oh so you had a loop that was going through to get the icons and when it would come across an engine with no icon it would error out of the loop so you would get null for the remaining icons?

Comment: Yes and because google was first it responded with null straight away. The others I happened to test were Yahoo, Bing and Wikipedia. Only Bing worked. After I added the check I seen the Bing , Duck Duck Go and Twitter Icons . It is not a major issue . I have the functionality was after so that is the important part. If I was stuck I could add the favicons in the addon myself and set them if the name matches.